# Why is Equatable not defined for optional arrays

Tags: swift, swift2

Can someone give me a good reason for why this doesn't work:

```
let a: [Int]? = [1]
let b: [Int]? = nil
a == b
```

This would be my proposed (if inelegant) solution. But it's trivial, so I feel like I'm missing a good reason why this isn't implemented.

```
func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T]?, rhs: [T]?) -> Bool {

    if let lhs = lhs, let rhs = rhs {
        return lhs == rhs
    }
    else if let _ = lhs {
        return false
    }
    else if let _ = rhs {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: In fact optional value is enum: 'enum OptionalValue<T> {     case None     case Some(T) }' that can be 'None' or your type, when you equal value to optional array it return type case that not be equal None thet return in case of second erray than stial have no type. In fact it is diffrent types when you do 'a == b'

Comment: The problem has been solved in  Swift 4.1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** Conditional conformance has been implemented in **Swift 4.1.** Arrays and optionals of `Equatable` elements are themselves 
`Equatable` now, and your code

```
let a: [Int]? = [1]
let b: [Int]? = nil
a == b
```

compiles and works as expected in Xcode 9.3. The workarounds are not
needed anymore.

---

*(Old answer:)*
Optionals can be compared only if the underlying wrapped type is equatable:

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

Now Arrays can be *compared* if the element type is equatable:

```
/// Returns true if these arrays contain the same elements.
public func ==<Element : Equatable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> Bool
```

but even for equatable types `T`,  `Array<T>` *does not conform* to the `Equatable` protocol.

At present, this is not possible in Swift, see for example
[Why can't I make Array conform to Equatable?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172) for a discussion
in the Apple developer forum. This change with the implementation
of [SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md)
in Swift 4.

Your implementation looks correct, here is a possible different one
using switch/case with pattern matching:

```
func ==<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T]?, rhs: [T]?) -> Bool {

    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (l?, r?) : // shortcut for (.Some(l), .Some(r))
        return l == r
    case (.None, .None):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't realize the reason I could do this before with non-optional `Array`s was only because of the global function declaration instead of an extension of `Array` to conform to `Equatable` where the elements are `Equatable`. What do you think about my proposed solution and why Apple would not have also included that global function?

Comment: @ScottH: See update. I could only speculate about your last question, but if you implement it for arrays then what about dictionaries, sets, sequences, ...?

Comment: It's a lot of DRY, that's a valid point. Though this would follow the same pattern as Apple has chosen with providing the `==` for non-optional arrays. It seems to be the best option until we can do something like `extension CollectionType : Equatable where Element : Equatable { ... }`.

Comment: @ScottH: My suggested implementation of the operator does not work (infinite recursion :), therefore I have removed it from the answer again.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into the same problem when initially trying to implement, which is how I settled on my inelegant solution. :)

Comment: @ScottH: It is not that inelegant, given that a direct comparison with nil leeds to infinite recursion. I figured out an alternative now.