# Swift equality operator on nested arrays

Tags: swift

Why does the last statement fail to compile with the error: `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[[Simple]]’ operands`, and is there a way way to modify the `Simple` struct or extend the `==` operator to be able to perform equality checks on nested arrays (or dictionaries)?

```
var i1: [Int] = [1]
var i2: [Int] = [1]
i1 == i2 // -> true


var i3: [[Int]] = [[1], [2]]
var i4: [[Int]] = [[1], [2]]
i3 == i4 // -> true


struct Simple: Equatable, Hashable {
    let message: String

    var hashValue: Int {
        return message.hashValue
    }
}
func ==(lhs: Simple, rhs: Simple) -> Bool {
    return lhs.message == rhs.message
}

var a: [Simple] = [Simple(message: "a")]
var b: [Simple] = [Simple(message: "a")]
a == b // -> true

var x: [[Simple]] = [[Simple(message: "a")], [Simple(message: "b")]]
var y: [[Simple]] = [[Simple(message: "a")], [Simple(message: "b")]]
x == y // -> ERROR! Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[[Simple]]’ operands
```

Comment: Your problem has been solved in Swift 4.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** Conditional conformance has been implemented in **Swift 4.1.** In particular:

> The standard library types Optional, Array, and Dictionary now conform to the Equatable protocol when their element types conform to Equatable. ...

(from the Swift [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)).

Arbitrarily nested arrays of `Equatable` elements are `Equatable` now
and can be compared with `==`. Your code

```
var x: [[Simple]] = [[Simple(message: "a")], [Simple(message: "b")]]
var y: [[Simple]] = [[Simple(message: "a")], [Simple(message: "b")]]
x == y
```

compiles in Xcode 9.3 if `Simple` is `Equatable`.

---

*(Old answer:)*
The reason is similar as in [Why is Equatable not defined for optional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244527/why-is-equatable-not-defined-for-optional-arrays). Arrays can be *compared* with `==` if the element type is `Equatable`:

```
/// Returns true if these arrays contain the same elements.
public func ==<Element : Equatable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> Bool
```

That's why

```
var a: [Simple] = [Simple(message: "a")]
var b: [Simple] = [Simple(message: "a")]
a == b // -> true
```

compiles.

But even for equatable types `T`, `Array<T>` *does not conform* to the `Equatable` protocol, compare [Why can't I make Array conform to Equatable?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172). Therefore, in

```
var x: [[Simple]] = [[Simple(message: "a")], [Simple(message: "b")]]
var y: [[Simple]] = [[Simple(message: "a")], [Simple(message: "b")]]
x == y // -> ERROR! Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[[Simple]]’ operands
```

`x` and `y` are arrays with the element type `[Simple]` which does
*not* conform to the `Equatable` protocol, and there is no
matching `==` operator.

You could define a generic `==` operator for simply nested arrays as

```
func ==<Element : Equatable> (lhs: [[Element]], rhs: [[Element]]) -> Bool {
    return lhs.count == rhs.count && !zip(lhs, rhs).contains {$0 != $1 }
}
```

or more simply (as suggested by @kennytm):

```
func ==<Element : Equatable> (lhs: [[Element]], rhs: [[Element]]) -> Bool {
    return lhs.elementsEqual(rhs, by: ==)
}
```

This makes `x == y` compile and work as expected. At present, there seems
to be no way to define a `==` operator on arbitrarily nested arrays.

Comment: Perhaps update the implementation to `lhs.elementsEqual(rhs, by: ==)`?

Comment: Suggestion: since https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md was not included in Swift 4, update the answer

Comment: @PetroKorienev: Done! – SE-0143 has not been implemented yet, but the special case for arrays of equatable elements has, and that is actually sufficient for *this* problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by implementing a `==` function for it, like following:

```
func == (lhs: [[Simple]], rhs: [[Simple]]) -> Bool {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but this question is way more complicated than what your answer implies.

Comment: @Jeff You are entitled to your opinion but I always prefer simple solutions over complicated ones. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) applies here.

Comment: My comment was not about preferring an unnecessarily complex answer. Your answer is not a solution to this question. Your answer is incomplete. The question is more complex than you seem to comprehend.

Comment: My answer is a solution and is complete. It is the simplest way of solving the problem that was described. You seem to make things more complicated than they really are.