# Linked List of 2D Arrays in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, linked-list, swift3

I'm trying to create a linked list of 2 dimensional arrays within swift and wondered if this was even possible. So far I have three main classes. The intention is for the other classes to run when the app is opened but only once per day.

However when trying to populate the linked list with a 2d array, an error occurs stating

> Type '[[String]]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

```
let arrayList = LinkedList<[[String]]>()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Swift equality operator on nested arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377761/swift-equality-operator-on-nested-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Array of array of strings doesn't conform to the [Equatable Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable), so `LinkedList` can't use it. It needs this to be able to do search and insertions in the list.

A work around would be to create a class that has a member of type **[[String]]** and conforms to **Equatable**.

```
class UberArray: Equatable{
  fileprivate var array:[[String]] = [[]]

  static func==( first:UberArray, second:UberArray )->Bool
  {
   //whatever logic makes sense for your use case
   //to compare to UberArray(s)
   return false
  }
}
```