# Check if array contains something - Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

I've found the .contains(Element) method pretty essential in my minimal experience writing Swift code, and have quickly realized that Apple changed it...

```
func contains(check:[[[Int]]], forElement: [[Int]]) -> Bool {
    for element in check {
        if areEqual(element, forElement) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
func areEqual(_ a:[[Int]], _ b:[[Int]]) -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<a.count {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I've been messing with some large arrays, so I fixed my problem with that clunky function.

What happened?

How do you use [the new way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains)?

The example there is well over my head.

```
enum HTTPResponse {
    case ok
    case error(Int)
}

let lastThreeResponses: [HTTPResponse] = [.ok, .ok, .error(404)]
let hadError = lastThreeResponses.contains { element in
    if case .error = element {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
// 'hadError' == true
```

Comment: What are kind of values are in the array you're trying to call `contains` on? Can you show some code of how you're trying to use `contains`?

Comment: Actually `contains(where:` is available in Swift 3, too.

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes made to `contains(_:)` or `contains(where:)` in Swift 4 – could you expand on what you think has changed? `[[Int]]` is not `Equatable` because we don't have conditional conformances yet – so you should use `contains(where:)` with an overload of `==` for nested arrays, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/33377761/2976878 for how to define that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about using this

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let contains = numbers.contains(where: { $0 == 3 })
//contains == true
```

Or

```
let strings = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
let contains = strings.contains(where: { $0 == "B" })
//contains == true
```

Even with other objects like `NSColor`

```
let colors: [NSColor] = [.red, .blue, .green]
contains = colors.contains(where: { $0 == .red })
//contains == true
```

Comment: invalid solution.

Comment: @VinitIngale this works for me, would you care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

That API just lets you pass a block where you can perform any checks you want. You can check whether the given element is equal to something, or whether its properties satisfy some constraints (such as in the example in the documentation). You should be able to perform a basic equality check like this:

```
func contains(check:[[[Int]]], forElement: [[Int]]) -> Bool {
    return check.contains { element in
        return areEqual(element, forElement)
    }
}

func areEqual(_ a:[[Int]], _ b:[[Int]]) -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<a.count {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The contains block iterates over every element and returns either `true` or `false`. In the end, a single `true` for any element will return `true` for the whole function.

Comment: @Hamish fixed the closing brace. Forgot about the nested arrays portion, taking a look.

Comment: I modified the code to use the `areEqual`function in the question since as @Hamish pointed out, there is no built-in overload for nested arrays.