# How to compare optional Dictionaries? Swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary, compare, option-type

In Swift we can compare optionals, we can also compare dictionaries, but how to compare optional Dictionaries?

```
var dict: [String: String]? = [
    "name" : "A name",
    "email" : "an@email.com"
]
var dict2 = [
    "name" : "A name",
    "email" : "an@email.com"
]


if dict2 == dict {   // Error line: Value of optional type '[String : String]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

}
```

This doesn't compile and forces us to unwrap the dictionary. Any clean solutions?

Comment: `dict2 == dict` is a logical evaluation rather than a value assignment... and the `dict`  is an _unwrapped optional_ while the `dict2` has been _wrapped_ initially... so what do you want to actually do here?

Comment: Essentially the same issue as in [Why is Equatable not defined for optional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244527/why-is-equatable-not-defined-for-optional-arrays) – only for Dictionary instead of Array.

Comment: The cleanest solution is to express this data as a Struct. Any particular reason to use a Dictionary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrapp your dictionary instance and then try to compare it.

**Using `if-let` block**

```
let dict: [String: String]? = [
   "name" : "A name",
   "email" : "an@email.com"
]

let dict2 = [
   "name" : "A name",
   "email" : "an@email.com"
]

// use if-let 
if let dict1 = dict, dict2 == dict1 {
   print("true")    // result is "true"
} else {
   print("false")
}
```

Updated value of dictionary 'name'

```
let dict3 = [
   "name" : "B name",
   "email" : "an@email.com"
]

// use if-let 
if let dict1 = dict, dict3 == dict1 {
   print("true")  
} else {
   print("false")  // result is "false"
}
```

Comment: It is not a problem for me to compare the two optional dictionaries, but I was rather interested why it is not supported in swift 3. I probably didn't express my question correctly. The answer is inside the link that @MartinR gave in the comment to my question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244527/why-is-equatable-not-defined-for-optional-arrays). I will accept your answer as correct though, due to your good will to help a fellow programmer!