# Why doesn't array conform to Equatable, when its items are Equatable in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift3, enums

**UPDATE:**

As of Xcode 9.3, which includes **Swift 4.1**, the array equality **works as expected**, and the code in the original question compiles without errors.

However, **please see the accepted answer**, because it provides a better, more modern solution.

The original question is below:

---

When I try to declare an instance of a generic enum with type `[Post]`, I get an error saying

> Type '[Post]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

which is nonsense, because `Post` conforms to `Equatable` and I can actually compare two `[Post]` instances with no compilation errors?

---

In the following example, I extend `Post` and `Result<T>` types with `Equatable` and then I do a few tests:

1. Test that I can compare two `Post` types: **OK**
2. Test that I can compare two `[Post]` types: **OK**
3. Test that I can compare two `Result<Post>` types: **OK**
4. Test that I can compare two `Result<[Post]>` types: **ERROR**

```swift
import Foundation

struct Post {
    let text: String
}
extension Post: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: Post, rhs: Post) -> Bool {
    return lhs.text == rhs.text
}


enum Result<T: Equatable> {
    case success(result: T)
    case error
}
extension Result: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Result<T>, rhs: Result<T>) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.success(lhsVal), .success(rhsVal)):
            return lhsVal == rhsVal
        case (.error, .error):
            return true
        default:
            return false
    }
}

func test() {

    // Test 1: Check Post type for equality: OK
    let post1: Post = Post(text: "post 1")
    let post2: Post = Post(text: "post 2")

    if post1 == post2 {
        print("equal posts")
    }

    // Test 2: Check [Post] type for equality: OK
    let arrayOfPosts1: [Post] = [ post1, post2 ]
    let arrayOfPosts2: [Post] = [ post1, post2 ]

    if arrayOfPosts1 == arrayOfPosts2 {
        print("equal arrays of post")
    }

    // Test 3: Check Result<Post> type for equality: OK
    let result1: Result<Post> = Result<Post>.success(result: post1)
    let result2: Result<Post> = Result<Post>.success(result: post2)

    if result1 == result2 {
        print("equal results of post")
    }

    // Test 4: Check Result<[Post]> type for equality: ERROR
    // Compiler error: "Type '[Post]' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'"
    let arrayResult1: Result<[Post]> = Result<[Post]>.success(result: arrayOfPosts1)
    let arrayResult2: Result<[Post]> = Result<[Post]>.success(result: arrayOfPosts2)

    if arrayResult1 == arrayResult2 {
        print("equal results of array of posts")
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays don't become `Equatable` when their items are `Equatable`. There is an operator `==` defined for arrays with equatable items but the array won't conform to the protocol. There's just no way to do protocol conformance depending on type in Swift 3.

Comment: See https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244527/why-is-equatable-not-defined-for-optional-arrays for a similar issue. It will change when https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md is implemented in Swift 4.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR for confirming this. I stumbled upon SE-0143 while trying to figure this out. I posted this question, hoping there would be a work around in when using the current version of Swift. I wonder how long it will take before SE-0143 will be in production.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately it won't be in for Swift 4.0, but the Swift team are hoping for some other version 4.x – https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/872211469856722944.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 4.1 update:**

With the introduction of conditional conformance in Swift 4.1, `Array` now conforms to `Equatable`, so the issue should be resolved without the need to resort to any workarounds.

Also, Swift now allows a type to automatically synthesize `Equatable` conformance, provided all its members are `Equatable`, simply by declaring `Equatable` conformance as part of the original type definition (not an extension) but without implementing any of its requirements. This works for enums provided associated values, if any, are `Equatable`.

The code from this question can now be written much more concisely as below:

```
import Foundation

struct Post: Equatable {
    let text: String
}

enum Result<T>: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    case success(result: T)
    case error
}
```

This code will pass all the tests specified in the question:

```
func test() {

    // Test 1: Check Post type for equality: OK
    let post1 = Post(text: "post")
    let post2 = Post(text: "post")

    if post1 == post2 {
        print("equal posts")
    }

    // Test 2: Check [Post] type for equality: OK
    let arrayOfPosts1 = [post1, post2]
    let arrayOfPosts2 = [post1, post2]

    if arrayOfPosts1 == arrayOfPosts2 {
        print("equal arrays of post")
    }

    // Test 3: Check Result<Post> type for equality: OK
    let result1 = Result<Post>.success(result: post1)
    let result2 = Result<Post>.success(result: post2)

    if result1 == result2 {
        print("equal results of post")
    }

    // Test 4: Check Result<[Post]> type for equality: OK
    let arrayResult1: Result<[Post]> = Result<[Post]>.success(result: arrayOfPosts1)
    let arrayResult2: Result<[Post]> = Result<[Post]>.success(result: arrayOfPosts2)

    if arrayResult1 == arrayResult2 {
        print("equal results of array of posts")
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
test()
/*
 prints:
 equal posts
 equal arrays of post
 equal results of post
 equal results of array of posts
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the update @khawer-khaliq. I have just updated my Xcode to 9.3, which includes Swift 4.1, and I can confirm that the array equality now works as expected, in both my original question, as well as your answer.

Comment: You are welcome, @Alex. The combination of conditional conformance and auto-synthesis of `Equatable` and `Hashable` conformance can make code much simpler and less verbose. I have been updating a lot of my own code as well.

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the question with a text urging readers to see your answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This issue totally sucks and still isn't fixed in Swift 4.

I worked around the issue by having a different type `ArrayResult` specifically for arrays of results, in addition to `Result`

```
public enum ArrayResult<T:Equatable> {

    case success(result: [T])
    case failure(error: Error)
}

extension ArrayResult: Equatable {

    public static func ==(lhs: ArrayResult<T>, rhs: ArrayResult<T>) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs) {
        case .success(let lhsResult):
            if case .success(let rhsResult) = rhs, lhsResult == rhsResult { return true }
        case .failure(let lhsError):
            // We cast associated Error to a NSError so we get Equatable behaviour
            // (Apple guarantee that Error can always be bridged to an NSError)
            if case .failure(let rhsError) = rhs, lhsError as NSError == rhsError as NSError { return true }
        }
        return false
    }
}

func test() {

    // Test 4: Check Result<[Post]> type for equality: NOW OK
    let arrayResult1: ArrayResult<Post> = ArrayResult<Post>.success(result: arrayOfPosts1)
    let arrayResult2: ArrayResult<Post> = ArrayResult<Post>.success(result: arrayOfPosts2)

    if arrayResult1 == arrayResult2 {
        print("equal results of array of posts")
    }
}
```