# Xcode force me to use contains(where:) instead of contains()

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I wanna check if in an array have already contained an item or not so I use to like this:

```
let fItem = FilterItem(key: String(describing: key), value: valueStr)
if self.filter?.filters?.contains(fItem){
    //remove the item if contains, append if not
}
```

For more information, the `self.filter?.filters?` is an array:

```
var filters: [FilterItem]? = []
```

And the `FilterItem` is a struct:

```
struct FilterItem {
    var key: String;
    var value: String;
}
```

But Xcode forced me to use `contains(where:..)` instead of `contains()` with error: `Missing argument label 'where:' in call`. Why?

Comment: You need to make your struct conform to Equatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `contains(_)` because the array of `FilterItem` objects doesn't conform to protocol `Equatable`. [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988705/why-doesnt-array-conform-to-equatable-when-its-items-are-equatable-in-swift) should help explain it. Basically, the array elements cannot directly be compared with one another using `==`, so they don't conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped :)

Comment: @Bad_Developer Okay it turns out I've got a bug already filed on the incorrectness of the error message you got: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8934